# What should I learn to develop event management in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have been tasked to built event management & registration page in WP like this page...

http://dunamis.co.id/programs

[image: event list page with filtering and pagination]

As seen there, this feature should able to filter event by category, month and year. And when I visit this page, event list automatically changed to nearest event in this month.

When I click "register now", it automatically forwarding me to registration page of that event. This page also has validation for field.

[image]

I'm also want administration page to add/edit/delete event and track registrant of event.

What should I learn to develop this feature? Thanks.. :)

Comment: That depends very much on a) what you already know, and b) why you've been tasked with this project. Are you really looking for advice about what skills/languages to learn, or do you just want to know how to build this?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to learn about WordPress is that it's not usually necessary to reinvent the wheel: many things have already been built, and are available as plugins. My personal favorite events management plugin is: http://wp-events-plugin.com/. It has everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plugin for your needs.

Check out [Writing a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) on the Codex. You might also want to buy this book [WordPress Plugin Development](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470916222) by Brad Williams.

But before that, did you try looking for an existing plugin like the [Events Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/) to suit your requirements?